# What is the expectation of $\frac{1}{X}$ for exponential distribution?

Tags: expectation, statistical-inference

I was trying to solve the following question: 
What is the expectation of $\frac{1}{X}$ for exponential distribution? 
Is $\frac{1}{X}$ unbiased estimator for $\lambda$. As the distribution function for exponential distribution is given by, 
$$ f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x},\ \ x>0,\ \lambda>0. $$ 
$$ E\left[\frac{1}{X}\right]=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}f(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} $$
Now, I stuck in evaluating the integral. How to integrate this or is there any other method for computing the expectation value.

Comment: from where do you know that your integral converges?

Comment: Yes integration is converging as I have plotted it in Geogebra.

Comment: but this is not a proof, have you got the primitive function?

Comment: No no if I got the primitive function then I am done with my integration but I am unable to do that.

Comment: if so should i write down the result here?

Comment: Yes please, then at least I can give a try after that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45560/discussion-between-sachchidanand-prasad-and-dr-sonnhard-graubner).

Comment: It seems that it should be $1/\bar{X}_n$ instead of $1/X$. Anyway, the second case is divergent, while the first can be computed using the inverse gamma distribution,

Comment: No, but in the problem, it is mentioned what I have written.